# cmake fail while configuring a project

Tags: 14.04, cmake

i have a project to compile ,this is the file readme of this project,

```
Geodesic Object Proposals
=========================

Dependencies
------------
Required:
 * cmake
 * c++11 compiler( g++-4.7 or higher, vc++2013 or higher, clang might work too )
 * Eigen 3.2 (optionally you can download eigen and put in in external/eigen such that external/eigen/Eigen is a valid directory)
 * libpng and libjpg (needed by cimg)

Optional for python3 bindings:
 * python3 (python 2.7 should work too, but I didn't test it extensively)
 * numpy
 * boost-python
 * matio (optional to load datasets)
 * matplotlib for some visualizations
 * MATLAB (r2013a on Ubuntu 14.04 tested, others might work too. You might have to specify a new gcc version in mexopts)
```

Acctually i use the ubuntu wich has a default version of cmake 2.8.12.2 when i tried to configure my project i chosed as a current generator unix makefiles ,should i downoald one of the c++11 compiler mentioned in the readme?
i have several errors

```
CMAKE_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY 2.4
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINIZEREL
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /usr/bin/cc
CMAKE_C_FLAGS
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINIZEREL
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX   /usr/local
CMAKE_LINKER    /usr/bin/ld
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM   /usr/bin/make
```

And many others
thanks

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu version 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

---

The most recent version of `g++` for Trusty is 4.8.2

[Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=g%2B%2B&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)

Installing with the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: Hello,thank u it really works, i have generated my project,since this is my first time that i work with ubuntu ,i wish u help  me by giving me the steps to compile and run my .cpp program.thank u for your efforts